# Looking for case studies and theory on citizen diplomacy

Tags: political-theory, international-relations, reference-request

[Citizen diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_diplomacy) is when average citizens of two countries work together.  It is useful when two countries have especially poor relations (e.g. may not recognize each other's existence). It is different from [track ii diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_diplomacy) in which government officials meet in unofficial capacities.  [Science diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_diplomacy) is a special case of citizen diplomacy where the citizens are scientists working together on some shared scientific goal.

I'm looking for resources regarding the effectiveness of citizen diplomacy.  I'm especially interested in case studies, but I'm also interested in academic theory.

Comment: Effective in what way? And are you just considering the scenarios where citizens are directly *attempting* to shape opinion, or also those where any impression is ancillary to a different goal (such as missionary work)?

Comment: Effective in the sense that the citizen diplomacy improves relations.  This could mean better publicity, increased trade, national recognition, or the increase in track ii talks.  I'm interested in both cases where improved relations is the direct goal and cases where it is an ancillary goal.

Comment: This might be a better fit for the History SE.